# extracting data from several xml-files with python

Tags: python, xml, excel, nodes

I just started learing python for my new job, so everything is quite difficult to me, even if the task sounds pretty straight forward.

I would like to extract several nodes from multiple xml-files, at best putting the information into an excel file in the end. Every row should contain the information from one xml-file, the columns should represent the specific nodes I am looking for, like "Zip-code" "town". Not all xml-files contain all nodes, so it would be perfect, if node "Zip-code" doesnt exist it just leaves the cell blank.

Could someone please point out a few hints how to start with this or, this is also possible, a special programm, which is easy to learn and use? My company and me only need to do it once for about 2000 files.

Thank you very much =)

Comment: Use BeautifulSoup4

Answer (score 2):

For opening the files and getting their contents, you can use the Python functions: [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

For XML parsing, I always use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). It's a HTML/XML parser with good documentation that mostly "just works".

For creating the Excel file, you can use [Xlsxwriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/tutorial01.html).

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your answer. I will try those hints and, if I may, will come back to you if I have a more specific question =)